# I am devoted to God, but doubts keep on coming in my mind about existence of God. Please save me. I want real devotion.

Tags: vishnu, shiva, gods, philosophy, devi

I am so much devoted to my Mother ShriLalita Maheshwari AdShakti.
When I was small I loved God, but as I reached 13-14 years, I thought that the concept of religion, God and others is a superstition, so I rejected all this. But as I grew to 16, I read various articles about religion, Bhakti, Yog, Ved, Purans. So I became very devoted to Mother Laita.

But now sometimes when I worship, doubts come in my mind that does Mother Lalita even exists or not. I tried to resist these doubts. But my science-based thinking keeps on making me doubt. I read Devi bhagwatam, Vivek Chudamani, various Stotram etc. a little bit. But still the doubt comes to my mind that does God even exist?
I read in Vivek Chudamani that this condition - "doubt whether God is real or unreal" is called ViPratiPatti.
But I then doubt is this Vipratipatti real or the author has just written it as such. And if Brahma really exists, why does It(from 'It' I mean the genderless Brahma), need to take form of Mother Lalita, or Shri Shiva, or Shri Vishnu and others? And if all these forms are true and complete Brahma, why should we worship any one of them and consider the rest inferior? And so many other doubts. So I feel that all the Ved Purans etc have been written only to establish  good rules to benefit people. 
But then again I argue to myself, if God is unreal, then why in many tantras etc. there is a procedure or sadhana to even get Darshan of God? But again I start feeling that maybe the Darshan is just because of some psychological reason or something. And even if mantra work, they might work by creating waves of fmvarious frequency and these waves effect the various mantra such as Mohan, Ucchatan, Maran etc. And no real God is behind the working of these mantra. And so many other doubts come to me.

I read BhagwatGeetaa a little bit, but I then questioned myself- is this Geeta ever been said by ShriVishnu, or is it just an Imagination. Is it just to benefit the old aged people, because when someone will become old, he may not be able to do anything, so some wise people thought let us create the concept of Moksha Sannyaas etc. for the benefit of these people. And maybe some wise men got jealous and they created other sects of getting Moksha such as- Gyan marg, Yog, Bhakti, Sadhana, Tantra, etc. And so many other doubts.

I want my life back. Please save me. I was really devoted to Devi. But these doubts are hindering me for the true devotion. And this has really caused a lot of mental problems to me like depression, fear that God will will punish me, preoccupation, lack of confidence, stammering etc. I don't want anything. I just want to know if God exists or not. I really want to devote myself completely to Mother Laita. Please save me from these doubts.

Comment: God exists, when there is faith and devotion, there is no place for confusion. There are various paths to the ultimate goal such as Jnana Yoga, Bhakti Yoga etc...Have faith in Mother Lalita, she always listens to true devotees like you.

Comment: Yes. God exists. Science must not be used to validate religion and faith. It is too inadequate to prove the existence of God. Devi Lalita exists. Keep worshipping her. She will reveal herself to you.

Comment: There is nothing to be worried about here. We all have Daiva and Asuri pravrittis in us. The gods in us will tell us to have faith, the demons on the other hand will be like obstructions to such devotion towards God. Such obstacles are overcome with praying, chanting etc which you have said that u are already doing.

Comment: Science is in infant stage to find God. Western Science is limited to Physical Universe but there are higher consciousness realms which can't be accessed by Physical body. We should cross all those Physical and higher realms (through Yoga) to reach or known our true self as **Satchidanda** (ever existing pure blissfull consciousness). Yes. It's quite common for any Science student to get these doubts. But don't doubt Divine Mother, she will definitely show you the truth. She will answer your questions of  purpose of this life and why you were born on this earth. Just don't lose belief in Her.

Comment: If you want to discuss this, visit [Vedanta and Philosophy](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/vedanta-and-philosophy) chat room.

Comment: Anurag, I will prove you existence of God but to understand the prove you have to go through Advait Vedanta & Kashmiri Shaivism to learn prerequisites.

Comment: @Fire. How do you prove?